# Add rows in a dataframe using values from another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=['proid','sku', 'qty'])
```

and a list of unique skus

```
skus = ["SKU1", "SKU2",  "SKU3"]
```

Now df may not contain rows for all combinations `proid` and `sku` where `sku` are from uniq list `skus`

e.g.:

```
#    proid  sku   qty
# 1  p1     SKU1   1
# 2  p1     SKU3   2
# 3  p2     SKU1   3
```

I want to add rows to data frame in such a way that all `proid` `sku` combinations exist with default 0 values

result:

```
#    proid  sku   qty
# 1  p1     SKU1   1
# 2  p1     SKU3   2
# 3  p2     SKU1   3
# 4  p1     SKU2   0
# 5  p2     SKU2   0
# 6  p2     SKU3   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and `concat`

#### setup

```
z = io.StringIO("""    proid  sku   qty
 1  p1     SKU1   1
 2  p1     SKU3   2
 3  p2     SKU1   3""")

df = pd.read_table(z, delim_whitespace=True)
p = ["p1", "p2"]
s = ["SKU1", "SKU2", "SKU3"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(it.product(p,s)), columns=["proid", "sku"])
```

Then

#### concat

```
df = df.set_index(["proid", "sku"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["proid", "sku"])

pd.concat([df2[~df2.index.isin(df.index)],df]).reset_index()

    proid   sku     qty
0   p1      SKU2    0
1   p2      SKU2    0
2   p2      SKU3    0
3   p1      SKU1    1
4   p1      SKU3    2
5   p2      SKU1    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that works well :

```
from itertools import product

combs = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df[proid], df[sku])),
                 columns=["proid", "sku"])
result = df.merge(combs, how = 'right').fillna(0).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

create a dataframe from a multiindex of all possible indexes

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
      [['p1', 'p2'], ['SKU1', 'SKU2' ,'SKU3']]
).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).rename({0:'proid', 1: 'sku'}, axis=1)
```

left join to the original dataframe

```
ind.merge(df, on=['proid', 'sku'], how='left').fillna(0)
```

outputs:

```
  proid   sku  qty
0    p1  SKU1  1.0
1    p1  SKU2  0.0
2    p1  SKU3  2.0
3    p2  SKU1  3.0
4    p2  SKU2  0.0
5    p2  SKU3  0.0
```

alternatively, create a multiindex & reindex the original dataframe, filling nulls with 0

```
ind2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(names=['proid', 'sku'], 
    iterables=[['p1', 'p2'], ['SKU1', 'SKU2' ,'SKU3']])
df.set_index(['proid', 'sku']).reindex(ind2, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```